# Correct break-down of elements for A/B testing?

Tags: ab-test

Let's say I want to test phone messages. I have identified a couple of elements I want to test and I have a few variations of each:

1. Music - no music, some music, continuous music
2. Voice - male voice, female voice

I'm trying to understand the better breakdown for A/B testing.

1. Should I test all of the Music variations (with no other changes) and then pick the best one from there and *then* try the Voice variations?
2. Should I prepare all permutations of all these variations (i.e. 6 different variations on the same phone message) and then pick the best result from that?

Answer (score 1):

You're interested in the effects of two different independent variables. If you already know or don't care how the effects will interact with each other (i.e., how the effect of music is itself affected by the gender of voice, or vice versa), you can run two separate experiments. Otherwise, you should run a single experiment testing all six combinations (not permutations). This is called a [factorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_design).